# custom QGraphicsItem unwanted behaviour after overriding mouse event

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to model a chess board and i want the pawn GraphicsItem object to be dropped in the center of the case GraphicsItem object .

i only implemented a mouseRelease event for the pawn object, it checks the list of items in the position, if a case is present i drop the pawn at the case position .

now when trying it in the window it works fine for the first move, but after that when i try to move the pawn it goes back to its original position i can still move it but its not under the mouse cursor

here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout,
                             QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QBrush, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF

class Pawn(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setPos(0, 0)
        self.setZValue(1)

        self.originalPos = self.scenePos()

    def paint(self, painter, options, widget):
        painter.setBrush(Qt.white)
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 30, 30)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        dropPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        dropCase = None
        for item in self.scene().items(dropPos.x(), dropPos.y(), 0.0001, 0.0001,
                                       Qt.IntersectsItemShape, 
                                       Qt.AscendingOrder):
            if isinstance(item, Case):
                dropCase = item

        if dropCase:
            newP = dropCase.scenePos()
            self.setPos(newP)
            self.originalPos = newP

        else:
            self.setPos(self.originalPos)


class Case(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setPos(100, 0)
        self.setZValue(0)

    def paint(self, painter, options, widget):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.black)
        painter.drawRect(0, 0, 40, 40)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0, 40, 40)

    def getCenter(self):
        x, y = self.scenePos().x() + 10, self.scenePos().y() + 10
        return QPointF(x, y)

class MainWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        view = QGraphicsView(scene, self)
        view.setGeometry(0, 0, 290, 290)

        case = Case()
        pawn = Pawn()
        scene.addItem(case)
        scene.addItem(pawn)

        self.setWindowTitle('doodling')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWin()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not implement the mouseMoveEvent as i confused it with hover behaviour.

this code works as intended

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout,
                             QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QBrush, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF

class Pawn(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setPos(0, 0)
        self.setZValue(1)

        self.originalPos = self.scenePos()

    def paint(self, painter, options, widget):
        painter.setBrush(Qt.white)
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 30, 30)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        movePos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        self.setPos(movePos.x(), movePos.y())

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        dropPos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        dropCase = None
        for item in self.scene().items(dropPos.x(), dropPos.y(), 0.0001, 0.0001,
                                       Qt.IntersectsItemShape, 
                                       Qt.AscendingOrder):
            if isinstance(item, Case):
                dropCase = item

        if dropCase:
            newP = dropCase.scenePos()
            self.setPos(newP)
            self.originalPos = newP
        else:
            self.setPos(self.originalPos)


class Case(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x_coord, y_coord, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setPos(x_coord, y_coord)
        self.setZValue(0)

    def paint(self, painter, options, widget):
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.black)
        painter.drawRect(0, 0, 40, 40)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0, 0, 40, 40)

    def getCenter(self):
        x, y = self.scenePos().x() + 10, self.scenePos().y() + 10
        return QPointF(x, y)

class MainWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        view = QGraphicsView(scene, self)
        view.setGeometry(0, 0, 290, 290)

        case1 = Case(-100, 0)
        case2 = Case(100, 0)
        pawn = Pawn()
        scene.addItem(case1)
        scene.addItem(case2)
        scene.addItem(pawn)

        self.setWindowTitle('doodling')
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWin()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```